# Поиск элемента кортежа по частичному названию

Tags: python

Задача создать поиск маршрута по названию города прибытия(to_). Мой код работает только в случае того, когда я ввожу полностью название, а нужно, чтобы работало введя несколько первых символов

```
def main():
    while True:
        ch = int(input('Введите действие'))
        match ch:
            case 5:
                choose_city = input(str('Введите город в который хотите отправиться'))
                city = ([item for item in routes if item.to_ == choose_city])
                if not city:
                    print('Вы указали не верный город прибытия')
                    continue
                else:
                    print(city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `==` на вхождение `in`:

```
city = [item for item in routes if choose_city in item.to_]
```

P.S. круглые скобки здесь ни к чему.